# PhantomJS: onResourceRequested won't fire for second page.open() on same domain

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I have two page.open calls that run in succession.  As resources are requested, I output the url of the given resource to the console.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

var resourceCounter = 0;

page.onResourceRequested = function (resource) {
  console.log(resourceCounter++ + '.\t', resource.url);
};

page.open('http://phantomjs.org');

setTimeout(function () {
  resourceCounter = 0;
  page.open('http://phantomjs.org/documentation');
}, 5000);

setTimeout(function(){
  phantom.exit();
}, 10000);
```

If I attempt to open two URLs on different domains, everything works as expected--I see a full list of the pages' requested resources.  However, if I request the same page twice, or two pages from the same domain (as in the example above), rather than seeing the page's requested resources listed out twice, I see this:

```
Resource requests for: http://phantomjs.org/
0    http://phantomjs.org/
1    http://phantomjs.org/
2    http://phantomjs.org/
3    http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans:400,700
4    http://phantomjs.org/css/main.css
5    http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js
6    https://s3.amazonaws.com/github/ribbons/forkme_left_white_ffffff.png
7    http://phantomjs.org/img/phantomjs-logo.png
8    http://phantomjs.org/img/icon-release.png
9    http://phantomjs.org/img/icon-ml.png
10   http://phantomjs.org/img/icon-bugs.png
11   http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif?utmwv=5.5.0&utms=1&utmn=1675561797&utmhn=phantomjs.org&utmcs=UTF-8&utmsr=2560x1440&utmvp=400x300&utmsc=32-bit&utmul=en-us&utmje=0&utmfl=-&utmdt=PhantomJS%20%7C%20PhantomJS&utmhid=1661770756&utmr=-&utmp=%2F&utmht=1398973179893&utmac=UA-21665893-1&utmcc=__utma%3D205055825.123505717.1398973180.1398973180.1398973180.1%3B%2B__utmz%3D205055825.1398973180.1.1.utmcsr%3D(direct)%7Cutmccn%3D(direct)%7Cutmcmd%3D(none)%3B&utmu=q~

Resource requests for: http://phantomjs.org/documentation/
0    http://phantomjs.org/documentation/
1    http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif?utmwv=5.5.0&utms=2&utmn=1424746795&utmhn=phantomjs.org&utmcs=UTF-8&utmsr=2560x1440&utmvp=400x300&utmsc=32-bit&utmul=en-us&utmje=0&utmfl=-&utmdt=Documentation%20%7C%20PhantomJS&utmhid=873610113&utmr=-&utmp=%2Fdocumentation%2F&utmht=1398973180268&utmac=UA-21665893-1&utmcc=__utma%3D205055825.123505717.1398973180.1398973180.1398973180.1%3B%2B__utmz%3D205055825.1398973180.1.1.utmcsr%3D(direct)%7Cutmccn%3D(direct)%7Cutmcmd%3D(none)%3B&utmu=q~
```

In other words, the results captured via `page.onResourceRequested` for the second page.open() call are truncated.

**Note:** I am seeing this behavior with the cache disabled.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to memory caching, `--disk-cache=false` will not help. As discussed [here](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10357) and [here](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/pull/11511), this feature is not available yet and will be a part of phantomJS 2. What you can do is download current dev (more [info here](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/PhantomJS-2)) and build it on your side as the feature is already [there](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/pull/11511#issuecomment-39071110).

Comment: Thanks--I was unable to find this!

Comment: I have PhantomJS 2 running, but I'm not seeing any difference with `page.settings.clearMemoryCaches = true;`. Perhaps the API has changed?

Comment: oh no, you're right .. read [this comment](https://github.com/ant0ine/phantomjs/commit/91cf016a1cd6e91a11a3516bb2366fd04ff235a9#commitcomment-5375396). Looks like the patch was rejected...

Comment: Maybe you can apply that patch for your needs but this could cause some problems in future with newer versions. Just keep an eye on it. Hope this helps.